# Python prometheus_client Counter error: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry

Tags: python, prometheus

How to check for existing Prometheus counters before creating them.

I need:

- If the counter already exists, I need to increment it.
- If the counter does not exist, I need to create it and increment it.

```py
import time
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Counter

start_http_server(8000)

while True:
    print(f"Update counters, time: {time.ctime()}")
    counter = Counter("counter_name", "Description", ["label"])
    counter.labels(label="label1").inc()
    time.sleep(1)
```

output:

```
Update counters, time: Thu Dec  7 15:14:18 2023
Update counters, time: Thu Dec  7 15:14:19 2023
Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'counter_name_created', 'counter_name_total', 'counter_name'}
Update counters, time: Thu Dec  7 15:14:20 2023
Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'counter_name_created', 'counter_name_total', 'counter_name'}
Update counters, time: Thu Dec  7 15:14:21 2023
Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'counter_name_created', 'counter_name_total', 'counter_name'}
```